# jQuery get data attribute and slidedown it's parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some links (see below) where i put `data-navigation` attribute, and what I'm trying to do is that the `data-section` attribute `slidesDown` based on it's data-navigation parent.

HTML

```
<ul class="main-navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#" data-navigation="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-navigation="explore">Explore</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-navigation="news">News</a></li>
</ul>

<section id="-navbar-home" data-section="home">
    <p>Home content</p>
</section>

<section id="-navbar-explore" data-section="explore">
    <p>Home explore</p>
</section>

<section id="-navbar-explore" data-section="news">
    <p>Home news</p>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#-navbar-home,
#-navbar-explore,
#-navbar-news {
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript /jQuery (I came so far, and cannot proceed)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li > a').hover(function() {
        var navigation = $("a").data("navigation");
        var section = $("section").data("section");
        $(section).slideDown();
    });
});
```

JS Fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/66qz2by8/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
var navigation = $(this).data("navigation");
var section = $("section[data-section=" + navigation + "]");
$(section).slideDown();
```

Comment: Also a note: `this` refers to the current `li > a` element being `hover`ed, so we get the `data-navigation` attribute of _only_ the link being hovered, as opposed to `$("a").data("navigation")` which gets the `data-navigation` attribute of _all_ `a` elements.

Comment: Nice it works! Kind of, how do I slide it up if the cursour is outside section part?

Comment: @Montague Try utilizing `handlerOut` parameter of `.hover()` http://api.jquery.com/hover/ http://jsfiddle.net/66qz2by8/1/ Could alternatively substitute `.slideUp()` for `.hide()`

Comment: @guest271314 thanks, it still works partly, the problem is that I have another links in the section box, but when I try to go there it hides..

Comment: @Montague _"another links in the section box"_ ? Is same `html` including _"another links in the section box"_ included at Question ? ,  original jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/66qz2by8/ ?

Comment: @guest271314 yea, sorry I forgott about that part.. I'm adding some extra content including links in the section box that user needs to access. http://jsfiddle.net/66qz2by8/3/

Comment: Perhaps ask another Question , including all `html` , `js` ,  description of expected result - at original post ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask